# Can jira post to slack with specific user callouts "@" by adding a comment?

Tags: jira, slack, slack-api

I am familiar with the basic jira + slack integration that allows for posting jira issue updates to a channel.

However, is there some way to make specific user callouts as part of those slack posts?  e.g. I'd like to be able to post a comment like: "@UserName - please review this issue" and have that generate a slack post that does a specific slack user callout to "UserName"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a given format to embed usernames in Slack.
**https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users**

> **<@userId>**

**P.S.** text type must be 'mrkdwn' as it does not work with 'plain_text'

When ***mrkdwn***
[image: When Mrkdwn]

When ***plain_text***
[image: When Plain text]

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work. it just adds the unformatted text "<@MyUserId>" to the comment text.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using text type as '"type": "mrkdwn"' and not 'plaint_text'?

Comment: How do you configure that with the python JIRA library?